# What server file system should I use for a small shop?

Tags: filesystems, network-shares

We are a company, where we have around 10 people working from OSX with images, PSDs, indesign and other graphic jobs. They would like to read and write from a network share, so all the guys have the work shared.

What file system should we use, for the network share (server)?

People from Windows, should also be able to read and write as well, to the server.

Sorry, but im not a server administrator, but i hope you understand my question!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some kind of server or NAS device, it really doesn't matter what file system the NAS or server uses - just make sure you can back it up.  Ideally it should use a file system which can backup open files.  The question you're asking really is what protocol do you want to share things with.

Seeing as you are all Apple based, I would however suggest you share your files & folders using AFP (*Apple File Protocol*), rather than SMB.  It's a proprietary protocol developed by Apple - it's like their version of SMB / CIFS, and it generally works better with Macs.

However, if you plan to add windows devices later you'll need to also share those directories using SMB/CIFS.

I have a ReadyNAS device (Netgear) which supports both of these protocols, (plus it also supports NFS, Rsync etc) and I've accessed it from Mac and Windows devices, so I know this works well.

Answer (score 0):

Use SMB share on OSX or windows server. There are plenty of NAS boxes providing it out of box.

Answer (score 0):

CIFS is almost universally supported these days.

CIFS is also known as SMB, Windows sharing, Samba, et al.

If you're shop is mostly Mac people then I suggest getting a [Mac Mini server](http://store.apple.com/us/configure/MD389LL/A?). If not then I suggest hiring someone who is a server administrator.

Comment: We have a administrator, but im trying to help him.
He says that he have alot of problems with permissions using SMB.

Comment: That suggests user/group/file permissions are incorrect.